# I have a problem with creating gym_super_mario_bros env and have KeyError: 'render_modes'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to follow "Build an Mario AI Model with Python | Gaming Reinforcement Learning" by Nicholas Renotte tutorial and can't move on beacouse of some error.

Here is my code:

```
!pip install gym_super_mario_bros==7.3.0 nes_py

# Import the game
import gym_super_mario_bros
# Import the Joypad wrapper
from nes_py.wrappers import JoypadSpace
# Import the simplified controls
from gym_super_mario_bros.actions import SIMPLE_MOVEMENT

# Setup game
env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0')
env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)
```

and this line of code:  `env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0')` couses following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16900\3897944130.py in <module>
      1 # Setup game
----> 2 env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0')
      3 env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)

D:\Anaconda\envs\gamesAi\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in make(id, max_episode_steps, autoreset, new_step_api, disable_env_checker, **kwargs)
    623     # If we have access to metadata we check that "render_mode" is valid
    624     if hasattr(env_creator, "metadata"):
--> 625         render_modes = env_creator.metadata["render_modes"]
    626 
    627         # We might be able to fall back to the HumanRendering wrapper if 'human' rendering is not supported natively

KeyError: 'render_modes'
```

I've already tried using python 3.7 instead of 3.9 and reinstalling packages

Answer (score 1):

Most of the custom envs are not yet ready for the 0.25 Version. Changing the version to 0.24.1 should solve the issue.

Try:

```
pip install gym=0.24.1
```

Kind regards

Comment: pip install gym==0.24.1

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to replace the error line with the following:

```
env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0',apply_api_compatibility=True,render_mode="human" )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: in short, _apply_api_compatibility=True_ option should be added to support latest gym environments (e.g. gym==0.26.2) which unlike the prior versions (e.g. gym==0.21.0) returns _truncated_ upon calling env.step(action) and supports the option _render_mode_ in gym.make().

Answer (score 0):

I installed the following packages verions:

```
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.3.0
cloudpickle==2.2.1
filelock==3.12.4
fsspec==2023.9.2
gym==0.26.2
gym-notices==0.0.8
gym-super-mario-bros==7.3.0
idna==3.4
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
mpmath==1.3.0
nes-py==8.2.1
networkx==3.1
numpy==1.26.1
Pillow==10.1.0
pyglet==1.5.21
requests==2.31.0
sympy==1.12
torch==2.1.0
torchaudio==2.1.0
torchvision==0.16.0
tqdm==4.66.1
typing_extensions==4.8.0
urllib3==2.0.6
```

Then use:

```
import gym
from nes_py.wrappers import JoypadSpace
import gym_super_mario_bros

env = gym.make('SuperMarioBros-1-1-v0',apply_api_compatibility=True, render_mode="human")
```

This worked for me. You should give it a try!